# How can I use InvokeListener in tapestry5?

Tags: java, tapestry

How can I convert this code

```
<span jwcid="permissionInEachStep@InvokeListener"
      listener="listener:onEditPermissionInEachStep"/>
```

into tapestry5 or have a different way to invoke method?

Answer (score 1):

you can rename your method as setupRender() if you want it to be invoked just before it is rendered. If you need it to be invoked several times within a loop then I guess you'll have to define your own component with its setupRender method and include it in your page.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Chochos' answer...
In Tapestry 5 you can hook into many phases in the rendering cycle. Here's a diagram of these phases, together with some explanation:
http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5/guide/rendering.html

You can hook into these phases by either adding an appropriate annotation to the menthod you want Tapestry to call (@SetupRender, @AfterRender, etc. -  see example in link above) or, as in Chochos' example, Tapestry will look for a method in your java page class matching the event name (you don't have to worry about case - Tapestry is case insensitive in this and most cases).